# How to insert into my sql table in wpf using Dataset

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dataset, sdf

I was wondering what would be the best way to insert a row into my sql table through WPF application window.
I have two wpf `DataGrid`s in my application, and I want the user to be able to push a button and insert data into the grid from there (inserting data into the sql table and refresh the grid when the user closes the pop-up window after inserting).
I´m using a `DataSet` database model and running .sdf database inside my application.

I´m using a `TableAdapter` to fill my `DataGrid`:

```
    HomeApplication.TheHomeApplicationDBDataSet theHomeApplicationDBDataSet;
    HomeApplication.TheHomeApplicationDBDataSetTableAdapters.AccountingTableAdapter  homeApplicationDataSetAccountingTableAdapter;
```

What is the best way to do this?
Any ideas would help. thx :)

Comment: Start reading this example and change the appropriate database connection , parameters and variables to fit your environment http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF doesn't help you for data acces. So you can do something like that `northwindDataSet1.Customers.Rows.Add(newCustomersRow);`

Comment: I solved this like that
theHomeApplicationDBDataSet.AccountingIncome.Rows.Add(null, "Wage A", 3000, null, "2013-01-01");
This is stored in my sql table and my wpf datgrid picks up the changes right away :)